Issue with dropdown-menu always trying to fit on screen vertically, even if it means overlaying the button for the dropdown itself
I am working in Angular 16, I am using Tailwind css and recently I downloaded ng-zorro for the sole reason of helping me with dropdowns and pagination. I have created a dropdown and a dropdown menu.
Here is the HTML file:

<div class="overflow-hidden">
    
    <app-title-card title="Open jobs" description="Discover Your Next Opportunity." imgPath="assets/Images/Open-Jobs.png"></app-title-card>
    <div class="mr-5 ml-5 mb-14 relative mt-6 ">

        <app-search-bar></app-search-bar>
        <div class="flex flex-row gap-8 overflow-y-auto whitespace-nowrap  ">
    
          

   
        
        <ng-container *ngFor="let dropdown of dropdowns; let i = index">


            <a nz-dropdown
        [nzDropdownMenu]="menu"
        [nzOverlayClassName]="'custom-dropdown-menu'"
        class="font-Syne font-normal text-brainport-blue text-xl relative active:text-brainport-blue"
        [nzTrigger]="'click'"
        [nzClickHide]="false"
        [ngClass]="{'underline-offset-custom': activeDropdownIndex === i}"
        (click)="toggleDropdown(i)">{{dropdown.label}}</a>
        

        <nz-dropdown-menu class="bg-brainport-blue"  #menu="nzDropdownMenu">
            
            <ul  nz-menu class=" rounded-10pix bg-slate-700 p-6 gap-2 flex flex-col ml-5" >
                
                <li *ngFor="let item of dropdown.items">
                    <label htmlFor="checkbox1" class="cursor-pointer relative flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                        <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" class=" relative appearance-none h-6 w-6 border-brainport-blue border-2 rounded-sm checked:border-none">
                        <img src="assets/Images/CheckboxChecked.svg" class="absolute top-0 left-0 opacity-0 check-1 h-6 w-6 ">
                        <p class="text-sm text-brainport-blue font-Inter font-light m-0"> {{item.name}}</p>
                    </label>
                </li>

            </ul>
          
        </nz-dropdown-menu>


        </ng-container>
        
        
        

    </div>
        

        <app-title-paragraph title="LOREM IPSUM" paragraph="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse semper ipsum augue. Nam ut enim vulputate, finibus lorem sit amet, tincidunt tellus. Etiam elementum at ipsum sit amet tristique. Duis posuere turpis nec ipsum molestie, et venenatis lectus condimentum. Donec suscipit lobortis augue, nec condimentum arcu laoreet a. Integer elementum nibh libero, eget vestibulum mauris aliquam egestas. Mauris in nibh massa. Etiam sit amet iaculis mauris, quis hendrerit quam....."></app-title-paragraph>
        
       
    
    </div>

</div>

And i have also changed the css file where i have overriden some things in ant-dropdown trigger and link to make it so the text of button does not glow with that blue color.
Here is CSS file:
.underline-offset-custom::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6px;
    background-color: #7AFBFF; 
    bottom: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 10px;
    left: 4px; /* Offset for underline */
  }

  ::ng-deep .ant-dropdown-trigger,
  .ant-dropdown-link
  {
    color:#1D1D7D;
  }



  #checkbox1:checked ~ .check-1{
    @apply opacity-100;
 }

 ::ng-deep .ant-dropdown-menu{
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color: #D2D2E5;
 }

Also here is my .ts file:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-en-open-jobs',
  templateUrl: './en-open-jobs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./en-open-jobs.component.css']
})
export class EnOpenJobsComponent {

 
  


  dropdowns = [
    {
      label: 'Category',
      items: [
        { name: 'Administration', value: 'administration' },
        { name: 'Agriculture and food industry', value: 'agriculture' },
        { name: 'Car industry', value: 'car-industyr' },
        { name: 'Commerce', value: 'commerce' },
        { name: 'Economy, finance, accountancy', value: 'economy' },
        { name: 'Education, science, research', value: 'education' },
        { name: 'Electrical and power engineering', value: 'electrical-engineering' },
        { name: 'Human resources', value: 'hr' },
        { name: 'Information technology', value: 'it' },
        { name: 'Law and legislation', value: 'law' },
        { name: 'Management', value: 'management' },
        { name: 'Marketing, advertising, PR', value: 'marketing' },
        { name: 'Medicine and social care', value: 'med-soc-care' },
        { name: 'Production', value: 'production' },
        { name: 'Technology, development', value: 'tech-dev' },
        { name: 'Top management', value: 'management' },
        { name: 'Tourism, gastronomy, hotel business', value: 'tourism-gastronomy-hotelbiz' },
        { name: 'Other', value: 'other' }

      ]
    },
    {
      label: 'Contract type',
      items: [
        { name: 'Full-time', value: 'value4' },
        { name: 'Part-time', value: 'value5' },
        { name: 'Freelance', value: 'value6' },
        { name: 'Internship', value: 'value6' },
        { name: 'Agreement-based', value: 'value6' }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: 'Salary',
      items: [
        { name: '800 - 1000 €', value: 'value4' },
        { name: '1000 - 1500 €', value: 'value5' },
        { name: '1500 - 2000 €', value: 'value6' },
        { name: '2000 - 2500 €', value: 'value6' },
        { name: '2500 - 3000 €', value: 'value6' },
        { name: 'from 3000 €', value: 'value6' }
      ]
    }
   
  ];

 

  activeDropdownIndex: number | null = null;

  toggleDropdown(index: number) {
    if (this.activeDropdownIndex === index) {
      // Close the currently open dropdown if the same one is clicked again
      this.activeDropdownIndex = null;
    } else {
      // Open the new dropdown and close any other open dropdown
      this.activeDropdownIndex = index;
    }
  }
}

What is happening is that if the menu is too big to fit on the screen meaning it would overflow at the bottom of the screen the menu does a thing where it shifts up above the button covering it completely and anything above the button as well.
Here it has space bellow
And here it doesnt
I have tried looking into the documentation for the library and forums, tried nzPlacement all the options but it did not resolve anything nor could i find anything about this kind of issue any where. I expect the menu to be always at the bottom of the button even if the user had to scroll down to view the full menu. I want it to shift only horizontally to fit on the screen so it does not overflow over the right or left side of screen which it seems to be handling well. I am yet to implement a function that will blur the screen bellow the button and behind the dropdown menu.
